# Lost keystore private key pass but I have a .pepk file

Tags: android, google-play, keystore, google-play-console, android-keystore

As question says, I've lost my keystore private key password (doesn't match the one I remember) but I have the private_key.pepk file, also I remember my keystore password. Is it possible to sign apk through play signing (its enabled) or my app is orphaned?